# How to specify .NET assembly trusts in group policy?

Tags: .net, permissions, group-policy

I have some .NET assemblies on a network share that I need to give FullTrust access to all of my users. What is the best way to do this using Group Policy?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it through group policy:

1. Lookup [caspol.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz(VS.80).aspx) in order to create a security group via the command line.  It helps to walk through the .NET security wizard and pay close attention to the window names and options selected because a few of the caspol commands are extra cryptic.
2. Create a [script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx) which runs this command.
3. Deploy via the Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts section of group policy.